# How to set static IP address to my mobile phone from APP on Android 11 when using USB tethering without rooted?

Tags: android, static, ip, usb, tethering

I have an app that comunicates with another device which is with static IP: 192.168.42.x. In the earlier version of Android, it workds all well because USB tethering always get a 192.168.42.y address for my phone. But as the "strange feature" : "ETH tethering" imported in Android 11, the IP policy was changed to random for USB tethering and that made my APP cannot communicate with my device again. It may get 192.168.50.x for my phone or else, and my device IP cannot be changed. They becomes to be strangers now.

Constraints:

1. Root the phone is impossible for me, as my APP will be dispatched for various users.
2. Android version: 11. As I described.
3. Networking is USB tethering.

I have tried for several different ways and get no success.
So I come here for help: whether there's any way to set a static IP address for my andoird phone and make it same subnet with my device that with fixed IP without root my phone? Or actually its impossible at all?

Any advice will be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: We have the same problems after an update to Android 11. The DHCP server of the phone returns a different address every time USB tethering is switched on.

We switched to DHCP on our client machine (Windows 10). But this causes problems when reconnecting the phone while our Windows app is running.

Have no solution - just to let you know that you are not alone.

Comment: @RasmusDebitsch Thank you. I think its a pretty common problem now. I wish Android will considering remove the ETH Tethering influence and get back to the stable subnet policy. :-)

Comment: any good news about this problem ? thanks

Comment: any update on this? I am terribly stuck because of this